# to display or not to display

Tags: php

I have a table inwhich I also use php's echo to display data inside td elements. Now I have another condition I need to apply for it as whenever the condition is satisfied the table is displayed or else it is removed/turned off.

```
<?php if(condition)
{
<table>
</table>  
}

?>
```

I would like to know which way to do this best and could help me not to type in " ' " at the beginning of each element's square bracket throughout the whole table ?

UPDATE

It's very simple to geeks and all the talented coders.

> if the condition is satisfied then display the table, otherwise don't
>   display anything in the view. Please remember also that inside my table I also use `echo > $data` etc to display table's data elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (condition)
{
?>
<table>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

I do not understand the second part of the question (about the single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one method out of given two:

**First:**

```
<?php if(condition)
{
?>
<table>
<?php //some statement?>
</table>  
<?php
}
?>
```

**Second:**

```
<?php if(condition) : ?>

<table>
<?php //some statement?>
</table> 

<?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is what you mean..

```
<?php if(condition): ?>
<table>
...
</table>
<?php else: ?>
 ... do something else in html TAG
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use quotes then yes the Logans answer is the best

Else you can use print or echo

All the best